# ssh (Putty) and X11 freezes/slows down with idle program

Tags: ssh, x11, freeze, beagleboneblack

I am using **Putty** to **ssh** my server device, and to visualize I'm using **Xming** for the **X11** forwarding.
The Windows computer is being connected to a Debian-Machinekit framework on my BeagleBone to operate a 3D printer.

Okay, so the problem is that I leave the ssh-x11 idle when a large GCode file is being used to 3D print the workpiece. After moreless 1 hr, Xming and the ssh communication freezes, or slows down to a point where the GCode lines keep running but with 10 seconds between commands. *A big problem when printing.*

I already tried to *keep alive* the connection, and to define my server as trusted X11.

My only "success" on keeping the conection is by applying **tape to my space bar**, and keep sending spaces to the ssh terminal. With this the freezing time decreases, but not always works out.

I show next my Putty configuration, and my sshd_config and ssh_config files.

Any advice is welcome.

**Client Configuration:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKFsr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjvx4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A25EX.png)

**Server files:**

ssh_config

```
   Host *
          ForwardX11 yes
          ForwardX11Trusted yes
           SendEnv LANG LC_*
           HashKnownHosts yes
           GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

sshd_config

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePam yes

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
ClientAliveInterval 60
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveCountMax 10000
UseDNS no
Banner /etc/issue.net
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, what happens if you run some program on the terminal that frequently updates the screen, `top` for instance? Does it still happen? Taping the space bar (pretty funny hack, btw) sends continous characters to the server, but `top` will send continous data from the server to the client, so I wonder if it still happens.

Comment: @aviro thank you for your suggestion, I tried with `top` and `sudo top`, but still I had freezing times / slow communication.

It seems it worked better when forcing data to the server, than from the server to the client.

Comment: It sounds more related to Windows, then. You said it happens after an hour of idleness. Is it possible the machine goes to sleep at some point? Or maybe changes CPU mode to save power? Here what I suggest (for analysis purposes): 1. Do something to make sure the machine is not idle. Before you just taped the space key, but try to play a movie, for instance. If after an hour you see it doesn't happen anymore, you'll know it was related to Windows idleness.  2. Try different ssh client other than Putty. Again, those suggestion are not possible solutions, but just ways to analyze the issue.

Comment: I'll try using other ssh clients, I don't think it is related to windows, because I leave the ssh connection idle, but I keep using the computer as always. Previously I thought my firewall was killing the TCP, but I already added a rule to the exceptions, no success with that one.